# How can I limit height of wpf datagridview based on number of rows?

Tags: wpf, datagridview

how do I set the height of the datagridview based on number of visible rows. Let's say I have a datagridview with datasource, having 100 rows. I want the viewable area to show only 10 rows. The other rows can be viewed with scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height is a dependencyproperty; you can bind the height of your grid control to the height of one gridrow * 10

Comment: Can you please post how to do this in XAML, if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You get the height of 1 of your rows... and then multiply by the number of rows you wish to see.

myGrid.Height = rowHeight * 10

(No one seems to know how to determine "rowHeight" correctly.  You also have to take into account the thickness of your borders between each row.)